# Steps to securing a new windows 7 pc and making it internet ready?

Tags: windows-7, security, internet-security

What are the major steps to take when securing a newly purchased windows 7 pc to make it internet ready?

Here's what I've done so far:

- Check the antivirus. (it's a free trial for 57 days of norton internet security, which I plan to replace with something else before the trial period ends).
- Check the firewall (configured by the antivirus to reject some incoming things and allow all outgoing, which is fine by me)
- Run all windows updates.
- Run the optional update to IE 9.
- Install google chrome & firefox (mainly just to lessen the security potential of windows browser-addition installs).

Going to:

- Set up the built-in backup system.
- Create a restore point.
- Install ubuntu via "wubi" dual boot.

What areas am I missing?

Comment: Install Linux. =)  Got an antivirus?

Comment: Actually, I plan to do that, via ubuntu's wubi, just so that I (and the computer's owner) have a backup os to use in the event windows does get trashed, and to give them an alternative os if they end up wanting to use it.

Answer (score 1):

With UAC Windows 7 is fairly secure, the most important thing is probably to make sure you run as a non-admin user. So the complete list I'd go through is:

- Use a normal user account
- Turn on the Windows firewall
- Turn on the Windows anti-virus - [Windows Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/security_essentials/default.aspx) - which is the newer version.
- Windows Defender [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/defender/default.mspx) to guard against malware.
- Let Windows Update install what it recommends
- Install Google Chrome and set that to be the default web browser.

That should be enough.

If you really want to you can install 3<sup>rd</sup> party anti-virus, but the Windows one does a good job these days.

Comment: What is "the windows one"? Windows itself, or a provided-by-windows antivirus product?

Comment: @Tchalvek - I was going to put "Windows Defender" but I wanted to check the name first.

Comment: Gotcha.  I did notice that the installed user was set as administrator by default, so that it something that I'll have to change.

Comment: windows security essentials is pretty much the free AV of choice for quote a few people. Its solid and fairly troublefree

Comment: Windows Defender is *spyware only*.  It does *not* detect viruses.  To get a full AV/spyware/malware product from MS you must use Microsoft Security Essentials.

Comment: @Bacon - thanks. I didn't have time to update last night.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the Microsoft Security Essentials and adjusting your firewall settings accordingly. I think the key thing is to stay away from sites that can compromise your PC. I would also recommend using IE9 (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home) as well.